# How to get file from a google drive share link using a PHP script?

Tags: php, download, google-drive-api

I need to initiate a download of a file stored on google drive thorough a PHP script. I have Uploaded the file to my Drive acc and have the share link for it. Any ideas on how that might work?

Comment: Provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show your code as it is now...

Comment: I haven't written any code for this specifically yet, since i have no idea where to start, the link does not point to a file it points to the drive download page

Comment: Take a look at the [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php), read [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) and maybe you will be fine. If not, open a question with your work in progress and the specific problem you need help. Good luck!